# CSP Header is refusing all scripts Spring Security

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, spring-security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am implementing Content Security Policy on Spring Security project.
I want to allow all resources from local server and some other resources(Scripts, stylesheets) from external links.

I tried different syntaxes but none of them work as they are blocking all resources and giving the below exception on all resources in console output

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com https://code.jquery.com
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://cdn.datatables.net
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maps.googleapis.com
>   https://chart.apis.google.com https://gyrocode.github.io". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-amABz7v3nBNObybd+IM='), or a
>   nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

This what I already tried, and some other tweaks

```
<content-security-policy
                policy-directives="script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://code.jquery.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://cdn.datatables.net https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://chart.apis.google.com https://gyrocode.github.io" />
OR
<content-security-policy
                policy-directives="script-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://code.jquery.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://cdn.datatables.net https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://chart.apis.google.com https://gyrocode.github.io" />
OR
<content-security-policy
                    policy-directives="style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://code.jquery.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://cdn.datatables.net https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://chart.apis.google.com https://gyrocode.github.io" />
```

I already reviewed the below links and other answers on stack but didn't solved my problem
[Configuring Content Security Policy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-csp-configure)
[Security HTTP Response Headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/headers.html#headers-csp-configure)

This is what people referring on other questions and I am still getting refusing errors

```
<content-security-policy
                policy-directives="script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com; object-src https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint/" />
```

Below is the domain list of external resources I want to allow along with all internal resources:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com
https://code.jquery.com
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 
https://cdn.datatables.net
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com
https://maps.googleapis.com 
https://chart.apis.google.com 
https://gyrocode.github.io
```

I am using Spring MVC with Spring Security on XML config, anything am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You've set `script-src` twice in the sample code and from the error message, the second one is being used and, as it doesn't include `unsafe-inline` it's being ignored. Remove the duplicated CSP and make sure only one is being set with the proper heading and it will work fine. Otherwise there's nothing wrong with your syntax.

Of course, if you can, it's always best to remove or manually allow include code with sha hashes (the hash the CSP message gave you will work). Whether this is practical depends on your exact code base and whether inline code is dynamically injected, which can make it basically impossible to go without `unsafe-inline`.

Comment: Thanks ben, I am not repeating those tags. I just wrote 3 examples that I have already tried but those arent working.
Yea we have some dynamically injected code which makes `unsafe-inline` necessary for us.